# The repository does not have a Release file

Tags: ubuntu, package-management, ppa

Hi I'm really noob on linux and trying to update with

```
apt-get update
```

but the command line returns me always

```
E: The repository "http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu tricia Release" does not have a Release file.
```

What can I do? I-m really lost with all this PPA stuff... Thanks!

Comment: What is a `tricia`? Never heard of an Ubuntu release of that name.

Comment: @muru it’s Linux Mint 19.3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't have a release file because it cannot find that `tricia` distro version, which is your version of Linux Mint. You should guess what's going on: you're asking an Ubuntu repository to give you a release file of your Mint version.

I see two possible approaches here: you either stop using that repository, or you lie to that repo and tell them you're running Ubuntu, which shouldn't be a problem considering that Linux Mint is a derivative of Ubuntu.
To do the first one, you should delete that line from the repo list. Find it by running:

```
grep "http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu" /etc/apt/sources.list* -r
```

Then, as a super user, delete that line:

```
sudo nano <file with that line>
```

If you insist on keeping that repo, then instead of deleting that line, change the `tricia` for `bionic`. Bionic is the version of Ubuntu from which Tricia was based.

Comment: ok, this is what i get doing the first command [/etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu tricia universe] but I don't know exactly how to use the second command the second command ...

Comment: Ok, I'll give you some backgorund so you get better at apt and can handle this kind of stuff. Apt will search for packages in repositories, but there are A LOT of repositories out there and you can pick and choose which ones you want to use. That picking process is done adding those lines (which are URLs and some metadata) inside the file `/etc/apt/sources.list` and the folder `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`.  
The first command gave you a hint: that problematic line is inside `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list`, so as a super user, you have to open that file and delete that line

Comment: Viendo tu nombre quizás sabes castellano ;) parecía que funcionaba con los pasos que me diste pero ahora me dice: [[E: El repositorio «http://es-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu bionic-backports Release» ya no tiene un archivo de lanzamiento.
N: No se puede actualizar de un repositorio como este de forma segura y por tanto está deshabilitado por omisión.]] 
He probado a hacer el grep igual para localizarlo y actuar de igual forma pero no encuentra nada...

Comment: Bien, por un lado solucionaste lo del repo que pusiste en el post original. Ese es OTRO repo, fijate en el enlace y entrá a `es-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu`, el sitio te devuelve un sistema de archivos. Entrá a la carpeta `dists/` para ver qué distros soporta, ahí vas a ver que `bionic-backports` está! Lo que no está es `Release` pero tenés otras opciones, como `universe`, `multiverse` o `restricted`, esa es nomenclatura típica de Ubuntu. Deberías sacar `Release` en ese config y poner alguna de esas 3 (o todas, separadas por espacios). Acordate de usar grep para encontrar el archivo a editar!

Comment: perfecto ya funciono todo a la perfección! Gracias!